# Set OS X Server for remote-only administration

Tags: macos, security, remote-desktop, server.app, remote-control

I have a Mac Mini with OS X Server in another room with nothing attached but the network cable. I manage it remotely using Apple's Server and Remote Desktop.

Is it possible to disable "locally" using the machine. As to avoid:

- Someone attaching a display and seeing my activity.
- Someone taking over the server control by ending my Remote Desktop session.

Cheers

Comment: WOW....., I was going to say put it in a lock box :)..but unfortunately if someone has physical access to hardware they can pretty much do anything with it.

Comment: I'm afraid that would be the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately as long someone has physical access to hardware they can do pretty much anything with it. (depending upon they skills).

Your only semi safe solution would be to put it in a [lock box](http://www.tryten.com/products/Mac-Mini-Security-Mount.html).

Then set up password for log-in screen and password for idle (sleep mode).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative was to use Apple Remote Desktop and remotely activate Curtain Mode effectively disabling any local control and video output from the machine (besides rebooting off course).